# Google App Engine Datastore Difficulties

Tags: database, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am using Google App Engine and using Google's datastore interface for a database . 
My question is this , I have the following code : I have a network object that I want to either update if it exists on db , or to create if it's the first time. . For this I have to catch an exception and repeat the same code twice - it seems ugly and redundant and makes me think I'm doing something wrong . 
The second thing that strikes me as odd is that there is no method I can think of that copies an object to an entity or vice versa . Am I expected to implement this myself ? It is very uncomfrotable to use the setProperty or getProperty for each property and well ...I am just wondering why there is no objectToEntity method or something of the sort.

This is how my code currently looks ...

```
try {
Entity network=datastore.get(KeyFactory.stringToKey(networks.get(i)._ipDigits));
//If I get here no exception was thrown - entity already exists on db.
Network contextNet= //fetch the network object from servlet context ...
network.setProperty("ip", contextNet._ip);  //update the fields using setProperty - no better way??
network.setProperty("offlineUsers",contextNet._offlineUsers);
 datastore.put(network);

 }
//Entity doesn't exist , create a new entity and save it (while repeating the same code)...
catch (EntityNotFoundException e) {
Entity network=new Entity("network",Long.parseLong(networks.get(i)._ipDigits));

Network contextNet= // ...fetch the network object from servlet context
 network.setProperty("ip", contextNet._ip);
                        network.setProperty("offlineUsers",contextNet._offlineUsers);
datastore.put(network);


                }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have to get and put the entity in order to update it. If you know the ID of the entity you can just put it. If it exists it will be updated, if not it will be created.
2. Use [objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) to automatically map your classes to entities.